# Event - publish and subscribe

Tags: c#

When I call this button_click method i want mymethod() to be invoked. At the moment nothing happens. I know I made an error. But not sure how to proceed. Any pointers ?

```
public class Program1
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        B b = new B();
        b.Button_Click();


    }


}

class A
{
    B b;

    public A(B b)
    {
        this.b = b;
        // subscribe to event
        b.SomethingHappened += MyMethod;
    }

    private void MyMethod() { }
}

class B
{
    // declare event
    public event Action SomethingHappened;

    public void Button_Click()
    {
        // raise event
        if (SomethingHappened != null)
            SomethingHappened();

        SomeMethod();
    }

    public void SomeMethod() { }
}
```

When I call this button_click method i want mymethod() to be invoked. At the moment nothing happens. I know I made an error. But not sure how to proceed. Any pointers ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are not initiating a new `A` which will subscribe to your `B` object:

```
B b = new B();
A a = new A(b);
A a1 = new A(b);  
A a2 = new A(b); // multiple subscribers to the same publisher
b.Button_Click();
```

Comment: incase i want to add more methods to the event how should i do?

Comment: by more methods you mean more subscribers?

Comment: yep more subscribers. one publish and multiple subscribers.